# how to convert binary into base64?

Tags: php, base64

I am trying to convert binary to base 64 using following code:

```
<?php
$bin = '00000100';
 echo base64_encode($bin); //MDAwMDAxMDA=
?>
```

but when using [online service](https://cryptii.com/pipes/binary-to-base64) to make sure I am using the correct method I get for the same input the following output:

> BA==

what I am doing wrong? how to fix this please?

Comment: You don’t have binary data here, you have a string consisting of zeros and ones. `$bin = 0b00000100;` would give you the result you want. If you get your “binary” input in text form, then you will have to convert it first.

Comment: @misorude how to tell base64_encode that this is binary data? is there a way? or anyway to convert binary to base64?

Comment: You're gonna need byte-wise [`bindec()`](http://php.net/bindec) / [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr)

Comment: _“how to tell base64_encode that this is binary data?”_ - not at all, because impossible. That function encodes a _string_.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php